# How do you send a number when you answer a get request with coap

Tags: get, resources, numbers, payload, coap

I've been reading the rfc 7252 for a while and I am probably blind but I can't find how can I send a simple number (integer or float) when you answer a get request for a ressource (for example the sensor /light, where do you write it in the packet.

I think it's in the payload, so I tried to send this packet :
the option content-format text/plain, charset=utf-8, length 1
then I write 255(0xff) in the packet
then I write 0x34 in the packet (payload part).

But obviously it's not working, first I don't think I should use this option (probably another one but I can't find the good one to send either integer or float number), I'm not sure though if I'm in the right way and not sure anymore of what I am doing tbh, so that's why I'm asking.

Thanks for help,

Good bye

EDIT : Here are more info : 
I'm using microcoap on arduino, using an ethernet cable between computer/arduino mega 2560.
[wireshark info](http://s7.postimg.org/dt1u5v1sq/coapimg.jpg)

Comment: Could you post some code showing how you are setting this up, and mention what type of language and packages you are using?

Comment: I added more information, with screenshots, do you need more information? (Should I add arduino code or is it fine ? Even though I feel like wireshark is enough, but as you wish sir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your Wireshark trace and seeing the response in Copper I think I see the problem. When you say that the `Content-format` is `text/plain` you are saying that you are sending ASCII data across. You say you send `[0xFF 0x34]` in your post, but in the trace you are actually sending is `[0xFF 0x33]`. Copper is showing you exactly what you are sending: 0xFF doesn't resolve as ASCII here and 0x33 is the ASCII for `3`, which is shown in the Wireshark trace and in your Copper output window. If you want to send 2 raw bytes of data that shouldn't be interpreted as text you want to set your `Content-format` to be `application/octet-stream`.